# Does the precision of the gem affect the amount of Stormlight it can contain?

Tags: cosmere, stormlight-archive

We know that an uncut gemstone holds much less Stormlight then a cut one.
Does this mean that the more precise the cut, (more facets), the more Stormlight it can contain?

Comment: Not precision of cutting but size and amount of flaws.

Comment: unless brandon mentioned it by a booksigning or something, the only mention of the ideal in the books is a "flawless gemstone" which presumably means that as long as the gem has no flaws and is perfectly proportioned it wont leak